# Design a layout sorting algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to make sure my items fit into the screen. These items are randomly generated and have a score of either 1, 2, or 4. This score lets met know how much space they take up on the screen. Score 4 means it takes up 4x the size of a score 1 item. It's important to note that an item with a score of 1 always needs a 'buddy', so they take up the width of the page.

I want to fit up to a score of 6 on my page, to an infinite amount of pages.
A valid result could be `[ [1, 1, 2, 2], [4, 2] ]`. Each array in the root array is its own page, so this would mean I have 2 pages that are properly filled since their child scores count up to 6.

Result:
[image]

This is what I came up with, but it's not so bulletproof. I'm not so good at writing these kinds of algorithms. Perhaps someone could help me in the right direction?

It's okay to skip items like I'm doing, but I'm also skipping items that might find a match later. Currently, all skipped items will be added to the front of `items` before `sortItems` is called again. So they will just be sorted with the next batch of items to find a new match.

```js
const getItemScore = (size) => {
    switch (size) {
        case 'small':
            return 1;
        case 'medium':
            return 2;
        case 'large':
            return 4;
        default:
            console.error('Unknown size:', size);
    }
}

const sortItems = (items) => {
    const maxPageScore = 6;

    let sorted = [];
    let perPage = [];
    let smallSort = [];
    let skippedItems = [];
    let currentPageScore = 0;

    items.forEach((item) => {
        const itemScore = getItemScore(item.size);
        if (currentPageScore + itemScore < maxPageScore) {
            // Item fits in page
            if (item.size === 'small') {
                // A small item needs to have a 'buddy'
                if (smallSort.length < 2) {
                    // the small item can be added
                    smallSort.push(item);
                }
                if (smallSort.length === 2) {
                    // we have found a buddy for the item
                    smallSort.forEach((smallItem) => {
                        perPage.push(smallItem);
                    });
                    // reset smallSort
                    smallSort = [];

                    // increment pageScore
                    currentPageScore += 2;
                }
            }
            else if (item.size === 'medium' || item.size === 'large') {
                // medium and large can always be added if their score isnt more than maxPageScore
                perPage.push(item);

                currentPageScore += itemScore;
            }
        }
        else if (currentPageScore + itemScore === maxPageScore) {
            // we have a full page
            perPage.push(item);
            sorted.push(perPage);

            // reset values
            perPage = [];
            smallSort = [];
            currentPageScore = 0;
        }
        else {
            // item doesnt fit in page
            skippedItems.push(item);
        }
    });

    // done looping over items
    const result = {
        sorted: sorted,
        skipped: skippedItems,
    };
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The intuition would tell us to come up with a recurrence-relation so we can reduce the problems into smaller-subproblems.

Lets say we are calculating for `size = N`
The top-section could either be:

1. 2 blocks of 1: `[1,1]` ; which leaves us with `size = N - 1`
2. 1 block of 2: `2` ; which leaves us with `size = N - 1`
3. 1 block of 4: `4` ; which leaves us with `size = N - 2`

Say, `S(n) = #ways to arrange these blocks`, then:

```
S(n) = S(n-1)  +  S(n-1)    +    S(n-2) 
      ^from-(1)   ^from-(2)    ^from-(3)

which becomes:
S(n) = 2S(n-1) + S(n-2)

with boundary conditions:
S(0) = 0
S(1) = 2
```

This makes it quite easy to solve:

```
def get_pattern_combs(N):
  if N < 1:
    return 0
  if N == 1:
    return 2

  lval = 0
  val = 2
  for i in range(2, N+1):
    new_val = 2*val + lval
    lval = val
    val = new_val

  return val
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example completly. Could you elaborate with some example input and ouput? (e.g. input: [1,2,2,4,1,4,1]) Also, I'm using Javascript and your anwser looks like python. It's okay since the concept is still the same, but I had to look up `in range` since I didn't know what it did.